# How to get Arg[I x] = Pi/2 for Real x?

Tags: complex

The argument of 0 + I x should be Pi/2 for any Real x. How do we get Mathematica to evaluate it as such?

```
ComplexExpand[Arg[I x]]

(* Arg[I x] *)

FunctionExpand[Arg[I x], x ∈ Reals]

(* Arg[I x] *)

Arg[I 3]

(* π/2 *)
```

Thank you Carl Woll. Silly me!

```
In[4]:= FunctionExpand[Arg[I x], x > 0]

Out[4]= π/2
```

Comment: It is `Pi/2` for positive `x` and `-Pi/2` for negative `x`.

Comment: Note also that the documentation of `Arg` indicates that "`Arg[z]` is left unevaluated if $z$ is not a numeric quantity", probably for the very reason that Carl mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, Carl.  Silly me!

Comment: Keith, it would be better if you included your last edit with the solution as a self-answer, rather than as an edit to your question.

Comment: Thanks, Marco. I have done that, and I'll remember for next time.

Answer (score 3):

As Carl points out, Real x is still too ambiguous as the argument still depends on the sign of x.  But:

```
FunctionExpand[Arg[I x], x > 0]

(* π/2 *)
```